# Show tooltip only for tab in QTabWidget, rather than whole widget

Tags: python, tabs, tooltip, pyside2, qtabwidget

I am using Qt Designer and a UI form. Targeted version of Qt is the latest PySide2 (Qt 5.x).

I have added a tooltip to my `QTabWidget`. In addition I have added tooltip to multiple other components in each tab (aka page). I noticed that whenever my mouse is hovering (for enough time to trigger the tooltip) above an area inside the tab, where no other widget with a tooltip is present, I would get the tooltip of the tab.

The behaviour I am looking for is to show the tab tooltip only when the mouse is hovering the tab's title. Otherwise I end up with weird situations such as the tab's tooltip popping up when I'm hovering let's say a button in that tab without its own tooltip. Ugly at best, confusing for the user at worst.

Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening? I have to admit I have rarely used tooltips in previous projects but now I decided to give that feature more attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [QTabWidget.setTabToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabToolTip) for this. It will only show the tooltip when hovering over a tab, unlike [QTabWidget.setToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop) (which is inherited from QWidget). This property can also be set in Qt Designer, where it's listed under *QTabWidget / currentTabToolTip* in the Property Editor.